# what is the use of AfxInitRichEdit2(); in mfc application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to know what are the different scenarios where AfxInitRichEdit2() method can be called.

Comment: Could you show us that you did look a little before asking?

Answer (score 3):

It just loads a specific DLL and with this DLL some window classes are registered into the current process.

In the past calling [AfxInitRichEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt1cfb9f.aspx) and [AfxInitRichEdit2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6hweatz.aspx) was the way to distinguish between two existing RTF window classes (Version 1.0:RICHED32.DLL and version 2.0: RICHED20.DLL). Just read the MSDN about the [Rich Edit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605.aspx) window class.

Comment: Until I added a call to AfxInitRichEdit2() to my MFC application, the modal dialog with a RichEditControl would not display at all.  When you add a RichEditControl, I believe a TODO comment is added in your class which derives from CWinApp in the `InitInstance()` method.